# HTML email text alignment & image issues

Tags: html, image, email, alignment

I an having a problem with my HTML email.
My email is working correctly in most cases, the problem arises when I send to windows live mail. 
1) opening the email in widoew live mail in IE all of the text becomes centered even though I have used the 'style="text-align:left;"' and the 'align="left"' options, I have tried them together and tried them seperate.

2)opening in windows live mail in anything other than IE the images have spacing below them. I have used the 'display:block;' and 'border-collapse:collapse;' and set the margin and padding to zero.
I used firebug in firefox to have a look and see what the problem is, it shows either a span tag or a p tag wrapping the img tags. I have no idea why it is doing this or how to fix it!

If anyone can help i'd be really greatful.

Thanks

---

no the align="left" doesn't work, If I use the align="justify" or align="right" it seems to work but not align="left". I have realised that I am only getting these problems when I send through outlook, I am using outlook 2007.  after some studying with firebug it seems to me that outlook is adding its own classes to the email. it seems to be adding either  or

around all of my images with classes that seem to belong to outlook. I know outlook is not the best program in the world but on some occasions it is the only way I can send emails. is there any way I can get into the code that outlook is producing and change it, I know that sounds a bit drastic but it would be really good if I could. thanks for all the help guys, really appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of mail clients support only older versions of html. gmail for example will not respect any css file (more information on email on acid) so you are restricted in what you can do with styling.

You can test how your email will look in various clients using online services such as email on acid or litmus.

I would suggest keeping the design very basic and using an old style table based layout.

Comment: In addition to this, there are a number of boilerplate templates for HTML email that claim to have numerous fixes for different clients such as Outlook, Gmail, etc. Do a quick Google search for HTML Email Boilerplate and I'm sure you'll find something to start from.

Comment: I am using a table design for my email, with the ccs inline. It just doesn'tseem to mater what code I use the alignment is always sentered when viewing the email in windows live mail(hotmail) in Internet Explorer. Or in windows live mail in any other browser the images become seperated.

Comment: If you're using tables does the align="left" attribute not work with the table tag?